# Selecting the second child of an ancestor with XPath

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I need to fetch some text from a HTML page. I'm trying to avoid relying on tag names or classes, because they will change.

Starting from an element that contains the text "Hello", I'm looking for the text stored in the grandparent's second element.

```
<...>
  <...>
    <...>
      Hello
    </...>
  </..>
  <...>       <!-- UNCLE -->
    <...>
      World   <!-- I need this! -->
    </...>
  <...>
</...>
```

I tried fetching the element UNCLE using XPath, with: `//*[text()=="Hello")]/../..[2]`, but it doesn't work. It seems that [] cannot be applied to `..`?

How can I fetch the second child of a node's grandparent?

Are there better ways to retrieve the text I'm looking for, instead of a similar XPath query and document.evaluate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```xml
//*[*[1][*[normalize-space()='Hello']]]/*[2]/*
```

It will select the element that contains "World".

It's testing the value of the descendant in the first child and then selecting the descendant of the second child.